# Fetch is sending wrong data format to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

```
handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
var data = new FormData();
data.append( "name", this.state.first_name + ' ' +this.state.last_name);
data.append( "password", this.state.password);
data.append( "email", this.state.email);
data.append( "phone_no", this.state.phone_no);
console.log(data)
fetch("http://localhost:8080/register",{
  method: "POST",
  body: data,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
        if(result.status == 'failure'){
             alert(result.data)
             console.log(result)
            }else {
                this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
              });
            }
      // this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    },
    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    }
  )
}
```

the expected data should be something like:

> { name: 'mayank', email: 'demo@gmail.com', password: 'password' }

what it is returning is

> { '------WebKitFormBoundarynYkonogmAGuTwWsy\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"name"\r\n\r\   nMayank nauriyal\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarynYkonogmAGuTwWsy\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name   ="password"\r\n\r\npassword\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarynYkonogmAGuTwWsy\r\nContent-Disposition: form   -data; name="email"\r\n\r\nma@gmail.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarynYkonogmAGuTwWsy\r\nContent-Dispo   sition: form-data; name="phone_no"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarynYkonogmAGuTwWsy--\r\n' }

Comment: Why don't you send JSON instead of form?

Comment: It is sending the right data, in wrong format. Change `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`, and change the body to `JSON.stringify(object)` instead of `FormData`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was stuck at this silly thing for 1 hr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send `JSON` instead of `FormData`:

```
var jsObject = {name: 'John', password: 'foo', email: 'foo@bar.com'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(jsObject),
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```